# Is there a jQuery control that does the following:

Tags: jquery, image

[image]

I need it to display 5 images of my choosing and be able to switch between them.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a carousel plugin.

[Here's an example of one called `jCarousel`.](http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm) *(Scroll down, and click on "pagination".)*

If that isn't quite right, you may want to do a search for *"jQuery carousel"*. You'll find several.

Answer (score 2):

There are zillions.  jQuery cycle is a good start:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

(Check out their pager demo.)

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm looking for. I need something like in the picture.

Comment: The plugin has settings you can customize.  Check out the paging demo:  http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pager.html.  Also check out the previous/next demos: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html